# multiple insert statements in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, bulkinsert

hello everyone i have a problem with multiple insert statements, i need to insert many records.i have written in this way but the records are not getting inserted into "userbill" table . help me??

.. here is the code:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = mySQLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "insert into userbill (billid, userid, date, amount, bill_status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    db.beginTransaction();
    SQLiteStatement st = db.compileStatement(sql);

    try{
        for(int i=0;i<Userid.length;i++)
        {

                st.bindLong(1, billid);
                st.bindString(2, Userid[i]);
                st.bindString(3, due_date);
                st.bindDouble(4, amount/Userid.length);
                st.bindString(5, "Due");

                long entryID = st.executeInsert();
                st.clearBindings();
        }

       db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
    }
    finally
    {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
    db.close();
```

logcat:

09-05 13:12:48.610: D/dalvikvm(7982): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 314K, 10% free 5030K/5568K, paused 17ms, total 18ms

09-05 13:12:48.610: I/dalvikvm-heap(7982): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.181MB for 1127532-byte allocation

09-05 13:12:48.614: D/dalvikvm(7982): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 9% free 6129K/6672K, paused 5ms, total 5ms

09-05 13:12:48.710: W/EGL_genymotion(7982): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

09-05 13:12:57.014: I/SQLiteConnectionPool(7982): The connection pool for /data/data/com.perfect12.app2maintain/databases/AMTDB has been closed but there are still 1 connections in use.  They will be closed as they are released back to the pool.

09-05 13:12:57.286: W/EGL_genymotion(7982): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

Comment: any kind of error message? Can You post the logcat?

Comment: thanks for replying but am not getting any error.

Comment: try to remove ";" inside the claims in Your statement string and be sure that UserId is not 0..

Comment: thanks for the reply . its working now after i removed the semicolon ";" in sql statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write

```
db.beginTransaction();
```

twice in your code.